# Get DISTINCT record using INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the follwong Query on multi tables

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.BoxBarcode as [Box Barcode], (select case when  b.ImagesCount IS NULL
        then 0 
        else  b.ImagesCount end) as [Total Images], s.StageName as [Current   Stage] ,d.DocuementTypeName as [Document Type],
        u.UserName as [Start User],uu.UserName as [Finished User]

FROM [dbo].[Operations] o
    inner join dbo.LKUP_Stages s on 
        o.stageid=s.id
    inner join dbo.LKUP_Users u on
        u.id=o.startuserid
    left join dbo.LKUP_Users uu on
        uu.id=o.FinishedUserID
    inner join boxes b on
        b.id=o.boxid
    inner join LKUP_DocumentTypes d on
        d.ID = b.DocTypeID 

where b.IsExportFinished = 0
```

when i select count from the Boxes table where `IsExportFinished = 0`
i got the Count 42 records, when i run the above qoury i got 71 records,
i want just the 42 records in Boxes table to retrived.

Comment: One of the tables you are joining probably have more records for each box.

Comment: Do the query with SELECT * FROM Boxes... and then find out which join is multiplying the result set. I'm guessing the Operations - Boxes is 1 to many relation

Comment: You can have multiple Stages (and therefore StageName) per Box?  you're including values from the Stage (and Operation table for that matter)

Comment: yes dear the box goes thru multi stages, the box go thru the stage once a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing a one-to-many join, i.e. at least one of the tables have multiple rows that match the join criteria.

Step one is to find which table(s) that give the "duplicates".

Once you have done that you may be able to fix the problem by adding additional criteria to the join. I'm taking a guess that the same `boxid` occurs several times in the `Operations` table. If that is the case you need to decide which `Operation` row you want to select and then update the SQL accordingly.

Comment: yes you are right the operation table i added in where condtion Where StageID = 1 and its work fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
SELECT
      Box_Barcode = b.BoxBarcode
    , Total_Images = ISNULL(b.ImagesCount, 0)
    , Current_Stage = s.StageName
    , Document_Type = d.DocuementTypeName
    , Start_User = u.UserName
    , Finished_User = uu.UserName
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
          o.stageid
        , o.boxid
        , o.startuserid
        , o.FinishedUserID
    FROM dbo.[Operations]
) o
JOIN dbo.LKUP_Stages s ON o.stageid = s.id
JOIN dbo.boxes b ON b.id = o.boxid
JOIN dbo.LKUP_DocumentTypes d ON d.id = b.DocTypeID
JOIN dbo.LKUP_Users u ON u.id = o.startuserid
LEFT JOIN dbo.LKUP_Users uu ON uu.id = o.FinishedUserID
WHERE b.IsExportFinished = 0
```

Comment: the same Dear the select return 71 records it must return 46 just

Answer (score 0):

I guess that if you change your LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN you will get 42 records as requested.